# Create Json schema dependency based on the negation of values from a key

Tags: json, jsonschema

```
{
      "eventType": "memory_exceeded",
      "event_time": 1544423819843,
      "clientDetails": {},
      "appDetails": {},
      "DeviceDetails": {}
    }
```

I'm trying to come with a json schema with the following condition in the above json structure.

1) There is a key "eventType" which can have 1000+ values.

2) There are 4 other dependent properties along with event_type.

3) I want to write a schema definition where

> a) If the "eventType" != ["x", "y", "z"], then include all the 4
>   dependent properties.
>
> b) If the "eventType" = ["x", "y", "z"], then include only
>   "DeviceDetails" as dependency.

Can I use OneOf for this? I know we can use "not" key for the negation check in 3a. But I'm not able to join the dots. Kindly help with the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If by *"then include all the 4 dependent properties"* you mean making them required properties, then I can think of this draft-07-based solution:

If `eventType` is set to either "x", "y" or "z" then only DeviceDetails is mandatory. Otherwise everything else is. (I'll let you replace these placeholder values yourself :)

I took the liberty of setting a `minProperties: 1` to `DeviceDetails`, `appDetails` and `ClientDetails` as I presumed that you'd prefer non-empty objects for these. If that's not necessary you can safely remove that from the schema.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "eventType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "event_time": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "ClientDetails": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1
    },
    "appDetails": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1
    },
    "DeviceDetails": {
      "type": "object",
      "minProperties": 1
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "eventType": {
        "enum": [
          "x",
          "y",
          "z"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "DeviceDetails"
    ]
  },
  "else": {
    "required": [
      "event_time",
      "ClientDetails",
      "appDetails",
      "DeviceDetails"
    ]
  }
}
```